# Sort n numbers between range [0,2n] in linear time

Tags: algorithm, sorting

> Suppose list *L* contains *n* numbers that are known to be in the
>   range [0, 2 *n*]. Design an algorithm for sorting *L*
>   in linear time.

I'm not too sure how to solve this. I believe radix sort is O(*dn*).

Comment: Is that `n` *distinct* numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like homework. What's about this algorithm in some pseudo code:

- Construct a flag array in size `2n`
- Forall numbers `x` in list, store `flag[x] = true`
- For i=0 to `2n` print `i` if `flag[i]` is true.

All iteration loops are bound by *O(n)*.

Comment: More review then homework probably should had mentioned that.

Comment: @CoolNewFriends - I see; mentioning that would have been prevented some downvotes.

Comment: Meh I don't really care about downvotes.

Comment: flag[x] += 1 for duplicate numbers support.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following:

1. Define an array of size `2n` initialised with 0 values.
2. For each item in `L`, increment `arr[L_i]`.
3. Loop through the array returning all items with value > 0.

This algorithm can be easily modified to handle non-distinct values in `L` by modifying step 3 slightly.